# On button click reload the page but scroll to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to reload the page and then scroll the page/window down to the very bottom of the page when the user clicks on "Add Another" button. I have tried jquery scrollTo and scrollTop functions but no use, it probably doesn't work on page reload, Please can someone help me with this.

The button that refreshes or reloads the page is "anotherEducation" and the div I want to scroll down to is "secondaryEducationForm"

```
<script>
function scroll(){window.scrollTo(0,750); 
 }
 </script>

<div id="secondaryEducationForm">
    <br/>
    <form>
        <label for="secondaryLevel" style="text-align:justify;">Select the level of qualification first (e.g. A level) then enter your grades and click on "Save"
        To add other qualifcations (e.g. GCSE's) click on "Add another qualification"</label>
        <br/>`

    <select name="secondaryLevel" id="secondaryLevel" onChange="showdiv(this)" style="margin-bottom:25px;">

        <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
        <option value="1">A Level</option>
        <option value="2">AS Level</option>
        <option value="0">GCSE</option>
        <option value="3">BTEC</option>
        <option value="4">NVQ</option>
        <option value="NULL">Other (Please State)</option>
    </select>

<input type="text" name="secondaryLevelCustom" id="secondaryLevelCustom" value="" style="display:none;" />

<input type="submit" name="saveGCSEEducation" id="saveGCSEEducationSubmit" value="Save" />

<input type="submit" name="anotherEducation" id="anotherEducation" onclick="scroll();" value="Add Another Qualification" />
</form>
```

`

Comment: Can you post some HTML/CSS? Have you tried an anchor in the footer section of the page?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect a link to a div on a page by doing

```
<a href="pagename.html#yourDivId">Some Text</a>
```

Comment: it works for the scroll bit but it doesn't reload the page :(

Comment: I'm not sure about this but try: href=".#idwhereyouwanttogo"
Or add onclick="window.location.reload(true);" to your link + the above code

Answer (score 1):

You have to store True/False value or Flage when user click on anotherEducation, and then reloadpage, after reloading of page check That value, iF is it True then scroll down, else do nothing...

```
   $(document).ready(function()){
   function scroll(){
      if(anotherEducation==true){
         window.scrollTo(0,750); 
         }
       else
         //Do nothing..
         }
    )};
```

Comment: I am sorry but how can I store the Flag values ?

Answer (score 0):

Try appending div id to url to and reload the page

```
 <div id="yourform">    Place where you wanted to scroll down on page
 load / reload </div>
```

Like this

#yourform